# Can someone show me a way to validate if my textboxes are not empty before the bootstrap modal can be activated/clicked/opened in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

Basically I'd like to have the modal button check if the textboxes before it are empty and if they are then the user cannot proceed until they are filled.

Here's the code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-signin-signup" action="signup.php" method="post">

              <input data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter a valid email address." type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email Address">
              <input type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
              <input type="password" required name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Repeat Password">
              <div> 
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Sign up as an Jobseeker</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Sign up as an Employer</button>
                <!-- Modal:Jobseeker -->
                    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Finalization</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Hello! Please add some additional information to finish the Sign up process.</p>
                            <i class="icon-question-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" title="This is required to receive notifications from the system."></i>&nbsp;<input type="text" required name="cellno" placeholder="63905XXXXXXX"><br>
                            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Finish" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- End of Modal:Jobseeker -->
                <!-- Modal:Employer -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">

                        <!-- Modal content-->
                        <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Finalization</h4>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Hello! Please add some additional information to finish the Sign up process.</p>
                            <input type="text" required name="fname" placeholder="Company Name">
                            <input type="text" required name="bpermit" placeholder="Business Permit"><br>
                            <label><i>Optional:</i></label>
                            <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Website"><br>
                            <input data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click here to finish" type="submit" name="register" value="Finish" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                <!-- End of Modal:Employer -->
              </div>
            </form>
```

A big thank you to anyone who can answer my question.

Comment: in simple words, you require validation to this form?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I just want to stop the user from proceeding before filling out the three required textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function() {
   //in case if all Available Text boxes within the form are mandatory
    var checkEmptyInput = $(this).find("input[type=text]:visible").filter(function() { if($(this).val()=="") return $(this); }).length;
    if(checkEmptyInput>0) {
        alert("Missed Entering a Mandatory Field");
        $(this).find("input[type=text]:visible").filter(function() { if($(this).val()=="") return $(this); })[0].focus();
        return false;
    }
});
```

you can use the above jQuery function to validate your form (in case, if all visible text fields are mandatory)

**Terms Used**

`$(".form-horizontal")` a jquery class selector has been used to target the element with the class `.form-control`, here in your case it is your targeting HTML Form. know more about [jQuery Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

`.submit(function()` an event to target when the form is submitted

`$(this)` here targets current element, know more about [$(this)](http://www.javascript-coder.com/jquery/jquery-selector-this.phtml)

`.filter()` this is used to filter the selected elements with a callback, here in this case, this filters only the empty text boxes

`.find()` this is fastest jQuery selector, here used to find only visible textboxes within the main Element `(.form-horizontal)`

Comment: the bummer, here, is that the OP didn't really learn anything. He inherited some code and then did a "WHO CAN DO THIS FOR ME". eh.

Comment: yup right @Bosworth99, will just update my answer with some references and details now.. Thank you.. :)

Comment: @Bosworth99, check my edit, to make out, am i doing anything wrong in my explaination..

Comment: Hey looks good. Ultimately SO is a learning tool, and the OP should treat it as such. JS validation is such a common topic that some very basic google searching would produce massive results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `jQuery` for that.

```
$(".SUBMIT-BUTTON-CLASS").click(function(){
   //replace the "SUBMIT-BUTTON-CLASS for a class which involves all submit buttons
   //don't forget the period marker
   if ($('#elementID').val()==''){...}
   //this check's if the HTML referenced value is equal to empty string, you can make a check for every input field you want to compare
}
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_val.asp)

**OR...**
You can put the `required` keyword on the end of the `input` element. This will avoid that the form will be submitted with empty input. Example:

```
<input type="text" name="something" required>
```

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest of validation, without jquery or any other library, could look like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("inputID").value !== ''){
   // proceed...
}
```

You leave yourself open to potentially malicious code, so additional regex'ing is recommended (script tags, etc);

A resource : [js validation](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/01/27/A-look-at-JavaScript-Form-Validation/)

Comment: where would I put the id? to the three textboxes?

Comment: I would add logic, checking each box, to the submit / click handler - whatever is launching your modal.